# NG6002 error makes it very hard to find the actual error

Tags: angular

We are developing a project for the past 5 years, so the code grew a lot. Now we are facing the issue, that even small changes which are not done correctly cause a lot of ' NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.' errors. The error causing this usually is at the beginning, which requires a lot of scrolling to the right position when the app gets recompiled.

Is there a way to disable this error, so the actual error can be found faster?

[image]
(note that this image is only an example, I did not get all the errors on a screenshot, because there are like 50 more...)

Answer (score 0):

I Upgrade Angular version 11 to angular 16, so some packages are deprecated, I am Used that deprecated package in sharedModule. so angular not compiling that package, its throw error in sharedModule importing modules.

its one line error its throw nested importing module.

If any one facing this issue please check your shared module include any deprecated packages. That main issue for my project after updating.